# places dropdown>network>ftp= opens in firefox not nautilius

Tags: nautilus, firefox, ftp, places

ubuntu 10.10 user upgraded to **12.04 LTS.**

**Gnome 3.2.1** with **fallback** experience.

opening a FTP (not ssh or sftp, just FTP) from places drop down will open ftp in firefox (which isn't even the default browser on my computer).  This is not an issue within nautilus side bar, it works correctly there. Only from the places dropdown is there an issue.

I see in Arch forums they have a bug for it FS#23564, wondering if we do?  or, if there is some settings i'm missing? new to gnome 3.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Nautilus is not set as your default application to open FTP links. To set this, you can edit manually the `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` file. You can also use [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) that can help you to set defalut programs. For this, go to Admins > System > File Type Manager.

Comment: It works, i have to add two lines at the end:
x-scheme-handler/ftp=nautilus.desktop
x-scheme-handler/sftp=nautilus.desktop